# Gnuplot shading between two curves for two data sets

Tags: gnuplot

I have gnuplot code to shade the area between two curves. I.e. an error region like mean +- stddev. The mean and stddev are rows in a data file. Now I have two such data files and I want them in the same plot. I just appended the plot cmds but it appears the second curve doesn't get the shaded fill. I am using pngcairo terminal.

Data1:

```
 0.550 -0.131323 0.280289
 0.570 -0.145116 0.264563
 0.600 -0.275901 0.298501
 0.625 0.031135 0.277453
 0.660 -0.302773 0.300036
 0.700 0.039286 0.372996
 0.780 -0.099013 0.294711
 0.840 0.007641 0.294503
 0.960 -0.033036 0.435880
```

Data2:

```
 0.500 0.013809 0.028914
 0.550 -0.025318 0.038805
 0.570 -0.081928 0.042251
 0.600 -0.083926 0.060722
 0.625 -0.043033 0.074957
 0.660 0.027737 0.109750
 0.700 -0.017666 0.098800
 0.780 -0.252330 0.240454
 0.840 0.069862 0.231550
 0.960 -0.123103 0.504706
```

Code:

```
 data1 = "data1.dat"
 data2 = "data2.dat"
 set terminal pngcairo size 1200,800
 set output plot.png
 set grid ytics lw 1 lt 0
 set grid xtics lw 1 lt 0
 plot data1 using 1:2 with linespoints lc "black" title 'Mean', \
      data1 using 1:($2-$3)  with linespoints lc "blue" title 'Mean-sigma', \
      data1 using 1:($2+$3)  with linespoints lc "blue" title 'Mean+sigma', \
      data1 using 1:($2-$3):($2+$3) with filledcurves lc "skyblue" fs transparent solid 0.5 notitle, \
      data2 using 1:2 with linespoints lc "black" title 'Mean', \
      data2 using 1:($2-$3)  with linespoints lc "red" title 'Mean-sigma', \
      data2 using 1:($2+$3)  with linespoints lc "red" title 'Mean+sigma', \
      data2 using 1:($2-$3):($2+$3) with filledcurves lc "tomato" fs transparent solid 0.5 notitle
 set output
 set term X11
```

Undesired output missing tomato shaded region in second data set. If it is possible to shade the second region I would wish that where both areas overlap a mixed color is applied.

[image]

You input is appreciated.

Comment: When I execute your code I get the error message `unrecognized color name and not a string "#AARRGGBB" or "0xAARRGGBB"`. Also, I don't see "tomato" as a valid color name in `show colornames`.

Comment: Did you try any other color other than `tomato`? It seems that the transparency for the second area is there, but no color was assigned. You can also use the RGB code instead: `... lc rgb "#FF6347"` (for tomato).

Comment: @Vinicius Placco. RGB code worked. Strange. I've used this URL to reference colors names. https://www2.uni-hamburg.de/Wiss/FB/15/Sustainability/schneider/gnuplot/colors.htm

Comment: OK, great! Even though writing the RGB code may seem extra work, I find it to be much more robust, specially when running gnuplot in different machines (with different terminal types), or when using more than one plotting program.

Comment: @GertGottschalk The link you mentioned is not valid anymore.
Now see here: https://www.fnu.uni-hamburg.de/outreach/tools/gnuplotxyz/colors.html
These are personally defined colors and color names. To get an overview about the "official" or "built-in" gnuplot colors codes and names: in gnuplot console type `show colors` or see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54659829/7295599